# Use Async/Await and return status in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-redux, axios

I'm trying to call another function with API,inside my `ABC` function to check whether `remaing` available or not.

if remaining available `retun true` else `return false`.below is my code.but my console log show `undefined`.i want to get it as `true` or `false` inside my ABC function.

```
export function ABC(data,callback) { 
  return  function (dispatch, getState) {  
    var res=  dispatch(Balance(data));

    console.log("Balance status",res)

    //rest of code
    if(res){
    }

    ................
 }
}

export function Balance(data) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    const url = `api/.../balances`;
     axios.post(`${url}`,
      data
    ).then(async function  (response) {

      if (response.data.remaing > 0) {
        return await true;
      }else{
        return await false;

      }
```

Comment: can we use promise here ?

Comment: I suggest stepping back from your current task and working through some beginner's tutorials on promises, and on `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 0):

For the function created in `ABC` to use an asynchronous operation's result in its logical-flow code, it would have to be an `async` function. The `async` function you've created in `Balance` doesn't do anything useful, nor does `await true` or `await false` in a `then` handler.

Naturally, if the function created in `ABC` is an `async` function, the code calling it has to either be an `async` function or use it via promise syntax.

```
export function ABC(data,callback) { 
  return async function(dispatch, getState) {  
  // ----^^^^^
    var res = dispatch(await Balance(data));
  // ------------------^^^^^

    console.log("Balance status",res)

    //rest of code
    if(res){
    }

    ................
 }
}

export function Balance(data) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    const url = `api/.../balances`;
     axios.post(`${url}`,
      data
    ).then(function(response) {
      return response.data.remaing > 0; // ***
    });
  };
}
```

(And is it really `remaing`, not [say] `remaining`?)

Comment: sorry for my mistake it's `remaing` and i have updated my code.also i have tried this.but same error undefined

Comment: @Tje123 - Then you have similar issues to the above in other parts of the code.